# Initializing a vector of vectors having a fixed size with boost assign

Tags: c++, boost, vector, repeat, assign

Having a vector of vector with a fixed size,

```
vector<vector<int> > v(10);
```

I would like to initialize it so that it has in all elements a one dimensional vector with initialized value (for example 1).

I have used Boost Assign as follows

```
v = repeat(10,list_of(list_of(1)));
```

and I've got a compilation error

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘repeat(boost::assign_detail::generic_list<int>)’
```

How can that be done?

Answer (score 92):

This doesn't use `boost::assign` but does what you need:

```
vector<vector<int>> v(10, vector<int>(10,1));
```

This creates a vector containing 10 vectors of `int`, each containing 10 `ints`.

Comment: Why is there `1`?

Comment: @anibey the question asked about initializing all vector members with the value 1. The second parameter to the vector constructor is value to copy.

Answer (score 54):

You don't need to use `boost` for the required behaviour. The following creates a `vector` of `10` `vector<int>`s, with each `vector<int>`  containing `10` `int`s with a value of `1`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v(10, std::vector<int>(10, 1));
```

Comment: this was the first answer posted, it's the best answer, and yet it is neither the accepted answer nor the most up-voted one.  sigh.  life isn't fair.

Comment: I think it's because it has got `>>` i.e `>` without space in between :p

Comment: @dbliss Just looked at the edit history and it appears the OP had deleted this answer just after uploading it. Maybe he saw the other person's answer after, he had finished his and didn't want to post to the same thing which other person did(even though he was first). Anyways, it feels bad for him.

Answer (score 6):

I will just try to explain it to those new to C++.  A vector of verctors `mat` has the advantage that you can access its elements directly at almost no cost using the `[]` operator..

```
int n(5), m(8);
vector<vector<int> > mat(n, vector<int>(m));

mat[0][0] =4; //direct assignment OR

for (int i=0;i<n;++i)
    for(int j=0;j<m;++j){
        mat[i][j] = rand() % 10;
    }
```

Of course this is not the only way. And if you do not add or remove elements, one can also use the native containers `mat[]` which are nothing more than pointers. Here's my fav way, using C++:

```
int n(5), m(8);
int *matrix[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
    matrix[i] = new int[m]; //allocating m elements of memory 
    for(int j=0;j<m;++j) matrix[i][j]= rand()%10;
}
```

This way, you don't have to use `#include <vector>`. Hopefully, it's clearer!

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main(){
    int n; cin >> n;
    vector<vector<int>> v(n);
    //populate
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
            int number; cin >> number;
            v[i].push_back(number);
        }
    }
    // display
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
            cout << v[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Input:

```
4
11 12 13 14
21 22 23 24
31 32 33 34
41 42 43 44
```

Output:

```
11 12 13 14
21 22 23 24
31 32 33 34
41 42 43 44
```