# Initializing a vector of vectors of ints in C++17

Tags: c++, c++17, stdvector

I have tried creating a vector of vectors in a class with a fixed size using the solution from the following thread but to no avail. [Initializing a vector of vectors having a fixed size with boost assign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13121469/initializing-a-vector-of-vectors-having-a-fixed-size-with-boost-assign)

Since it's 7 years old, I'm thinking it could be something to do with C++17 changes, but I'm unsure where the issue is otherwise. The error the IDE tells me is "expected a type specifier" on the first argument. Having a look at the documentation for constructors, nothing seems wrong, unless I missed something.

```
class SudokuSolver {

public:
    SudokuSolver() {}

    ~SudokuSolver() {}

private:
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> sudoku_field(9, std::vector<int>(9, 0));
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use squiggly brackets to let the compiler know you're trying to call a constructor:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> sudoku_field{9, std::vector<int>(9, 0)};
```

Alternatively, you could do this work in the initialization list of your default constructor:

```
SudokuSolver() : sudoku_field(9, std::vector<int>(9, 0)) {}
```

And then run your default constructor from every new constructor you make to ensure that gets set:

```
SudokuSolver(int thing) : SudokuSolver() { }
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I keep forgetting that that is a quirk C++ has. I remember what the problem is now.

Comment: This works in this case but using that notation is risky with `std::vector` because it will try its hardest to interpret it as a list of element. It will only use another constructor if it is impossible to interpret it as a list of elements.